# Rails 4: how to solve wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3..4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I'm working on a PDF generator which has to generate from dynamically created forms HTML views in the platform I'm building. 
My issue is that when I press the button for generating the PDF I'm receiving this error: **wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3..4)**
I'm trying to resolve this but without success. 
Version Rails 4.2.6.

The CTRL and the export acctions are in the end:

```
class StudyVersionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :authorized?
  before_action :set_study_version, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
    obtain_token
    if @token.nil?
      flash[:error] = "The study is locked for editing by another user."
      redirect_to request.referer
    else
      current_id = @study_version.id
      @study_version = @study_version.edit_version
      if current_id != @study_version.id
        AuditTrail.update_item_event(current_user, @study.identifier, @study_version.semantic_version, "Study version created")
      end
      AuditTrail.update_item_event(current_user, @study.identifier, @study_version.semantic_version, "Study version updated")
    end
  end

  def status
    obtain_token
    if @token.nil?
      flash[:error] = "The study is locked for editing by another user."
      redirect_to request.referer
    end
  end

  def update_status
    find_token
    if @token.nil?
      flash[:error] = "The changes were not saved as the edit lock has timed out."
    else
      @study_version.update_state(the_params)
      AuditTrail.update_item_event(current_user, @study.identifier, @study_version.semantic_version, "Study version updated")
      @token.release
    end
    redirect_to history_study_path(@study)
  end

  def soa
    @study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    render text: @study_version.soa.html_safe
  end

  def clear
    find_token
    if @token.nil?
      render :json => {:errors => ["The changes were not saved as the edit lock has timed out."]}, :status => 422
    else
      result = Visit.where(study_version_id: params[:id]).destroy_all
      result = Form.where(study_version_id: params[:id]).destroy_all
      render :json => {}, :status => 200
    end
  end

  def update
    find_token
    if @token.nil?
      render :json => {:errors => ["The changes were not saved as the edit lock has timed out."]}, :status => 422
    else
      @study_version.update(the_params)
      if @study_version.errors.empty?
        render json: { data: @study_version.to_hash }, :status => 200
      else
        render :json => { :errors => @study_version.errors.full_messages}, :status => 422
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    @study = Study.find(@study_version.study_id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: { data: @study_version.to_hash }, :status => 200
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    obtain_token
    if @token.nil?
      flash[:error] = "The study is locked for editing by another user."
    else
      @study_version.destroy
      AuditTrail.delete_item_event(current_user, @study.identifier, @study_version.semantic_version, "Study version deleted")
      @token.release
    end
    redirect_to history_study_path(@study)
  end

  def export
    study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    study = Study.find(study_version.study_id)
    lock = Token.obtain("#{study.identifier}_#{the_params[:export_type].upcase}", "", current_user)
    if !lock.nil?
      @lock_id = lock.id
      case the_params[:export_type]
        when "json"
          @path = export_json_study_version_path(study_version)
        when "odm"
          @path = export_odm_study_version_path(study_version)
        when "als"
          @path = export_als_study_version_path(study_version)
        when "crf"
          @path = export_crf_study_version_path(study_version)
        when "acrf"
          @path = export_acrf_study_version_path(study_version)
        else
          @path = export_json_study_version_path(study_version) # Default to JSON for the moment
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {render :layout => 'export'}
      end
    else
      @lock_id = 0
      respond_to do |format|
        flash[:error] = "Someone else is curently exporting this item. Try again in a minute."
        format.html {render :layout => 'export'}
      end
    end
  end

  def export_json
    study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    study = Study.find(study_version.study_id)
    lock = Token.obtain("#{study.identifier}_JSON", "", current_user)
    study = Study.find(study_version.study_id)
    hash = study_version.to_full_hash
    send_data hash.to_json, filename: "#{study_version.name}.json", :type => 'application/json; header=present', disposition: "attachment"
    lock.release
  end

  def export_odm
    study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    study = Study.find(study_version.study_id)
    lock = Token.obtain("#{study.identifier}_ODM", "", current_user)
    xml = study_version.to_xml
    send_data xml, filename: "#{study_version.name}.xml", :type => 'application/xhtml+xml; header=present', disposition: "attachment"
    lock.release
  end

  def export_als
    study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    study = Study.find(study_version.study_id)
    lock = Token.obtain("#{study.identifier}_ALS", "", current_user)
    filename = "#{study_version.name}.xls"
    result = study_version.to_als(filename)
    lock.release
    if result[:error_count] == 0
      send_file result[:full_path], :type => "application/vnd.ms-excel", :filename => filename, :stream => false
    else
      flash[:error] = result[:error_message]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {render :layout => 'export'}
      end
    end
  end

  def export_crf
    html = ""
    study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    study = Study.find(study_version.study_id)
    lock = Token.obtain("#{study.identifier}_CRF", "", current_user)
    forms = Form.where(study_version_id: study_version.id).order('ordinal asc')
    forms.each do |form|
      html += PdfReport.page_break
      # html += CdiscChangesReport.page_break
      html += Mdr.form_to_html(form.form_id, form.form_namespace, true).html_safe
    end
    pdf = PdfReport.create("Case Report Form", "#{study.label}", current_user, html)
    send_data pdf, filename: "#{study.identifier}_CRF.pdf", type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'attachment' #'inline'
    lock.release
  end

  def export_acrf
    html = ""
    study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    study = Study.find(study_version.study_id)
    lock = Token.obtain("#{study.identifier}_ACRF", "", current_user)
    forms = Form.where(study_version_id: study_version.id).order('ordinal asc')
    forms.each do |form|
      html += PdfReport.page_break
      # html += CdiscChangesReport.page_break
      html += Mdr.form_to_html_annotations(form.form_id, form.form_namespace, true).html_safe
    end
    #pdf = PdfReport.create("Annotated CRF", "#{study.label}", current_user, html)
    pdf = PdfReport.create("Annotated CRF", "#{study.label}", current_user, html)
    send_data pdf, filename: "#{study.identifier}_aCRF.pdf", type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'attachment' #'inline'
    lock.release
  end

private

  def obtain_token
    @study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    @study = Study.find(@study_version.study_id)
    @token = Token.obtain(@study.identifier, @study_version.semantic_version, current_user)
    return @token
  end

  def find_token
    @study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    @study = Study.find(@study_version.study_id)
    @token = Token.find_token(@study.identifier, current_user)
    return @token
  end

  def authorized?
    authorize StudyVersion
  end

  def the_params
    params.require(:study_version).permit(:study_id, :name, :description, :protocol_name, :state, :export_type)
  end   

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_study_version
    @study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

The Model and in the line pdf = CdiscChangesReport.new.create I have the error:

```
class PdfReport

  C_CLASS_NAME = "PdfReport"

  def self.create(title, sub_title, user, body_html)
    paper_size = "A4"
    html = page_header()
    html += title_page(title, sub_title, user)
    # Document history
    html += body_html
    # Completion instructions
    html += page_footer()
    #ConsoleLogger.log(C_CLASS_NAME, "create", "HTML=" + html.to_s)
    #pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html, :page_size => paper_size, :footer => {:font_size => "10", :font_name => "Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif", :left => "", :center => "", :right => "[page] of [topage]"} )
    pdf = CdiscChangesReport.new.create(html, :page_size => paper_size, :footer => {:font_size => "10", :font_name => "Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif", :left => "", :center => "", :right => "[page] of [topage]"} )

    return pdf
  end

  def self.page_header
    html = "<html><head>"
    html += "<style>"
    html += "h1 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 34pt; }\n"
    html += "h1.title { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 30pt; text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }\n"
    html += "h2 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; line-height: 28pt; }\n"
    html += "h2.title { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; line-height: 24pt; text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }\n"
    html += "h3 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; }\n"
    html += "h4 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt; }\n"
    html += "h5 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; }\n"
    html += "p { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; }\n"
    html += "table tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.simple { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.simple tr td { border: 1px solid black; font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.simple tr th { border: 1px solid black; font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table h4 { vertical-align: middle;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table td:first-child{ font: bold; }\n"
    html += "table.form_repeat { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.form_repeat th { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; }\n"
    html += "table.form_repeat tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;}\n"
    html += "table.details tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 1px; }\n"
    html += "table.ci { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;}\n"
    html += "table.ci tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1pt solid black; }\n"
    html += ".ci td table, .ci td table tbody, .ci td table td { border:none; }\n" # Stops inheritence into markdown
    html += "table.note { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.note tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; font: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; }\n"
    html += "table.input_field { border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}\n"
    html += "table.input_field tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; text-align: center; vertical-align: center; padding: 5px; }\n"
    html += "table.input_field td:not(:last-child){border-right: 1px dashed}\n"
    html += "table.cl_field tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: center; padding: 2px; }\n"
    html += "table.cl_field td:first-child{ border: 1px solid black; }\n"
    html += "tr.warning { background-color: #fcf8e3 !important; }\n"
    html += "</style>"
    html += "</head><body>"
    return html
  end

  def self.page_footer
    html = "</body></html>"
    return html
  end

  def self.title_page(title, sub_title, user)
    name = ENV['organization_title']
    image_file = ENV['organization_image_file']
    dir = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images")
    file = File.join(dir, image_file)
    time_generated = Time.now
    # Generate HTML
    html = "<br><br><div style=\"text-align: center;\"><img src=\"#{file}\" style=\"height:75px;\"></div>"
    html += "<h2 class=\"title\">#{name}</h2>"
    html += "<br>" * 10
    html += "<h1 class=\"title\">#{title}<br>#{sub_title}</h1>"
    html += "<br>" * 23
    html += "<table class=\"details\" align=\"right\"><tr><td>Run at:</td><td>#{time_generated.strftime("%Y-%b-%d, %H:%M:%S")}</td></tr><tr><td>Run by:</td><td>#{user.email}</td></tr></table>"
    html += page_break
    return html
  end

  def self.page_break
    return "<p style='page-break-after:always;'></p>"
  end

end
```

Comment: Where does this `CdiscChangesReport` class come from? What's its source? You probably initialize it wrong way (you pass 2 parameters into constructor, but it expect 3 or 4).

Comment: It is coming from a gem https://github.com/Jakub41/pdf-report-generator @MarekLipka

Comment: how do you call `def self.create(title, sub_title, user, body_html)` and how do you call `CdiscChangesReport.new.create(html, :page_size => paper_size, :footer => {etc..etc..etc..."} )` we would like to see your parameters

Answer (score 0):

You call `CdiscChangesReport#create` with two parameters while it accepts 3 or 4, according to its source here:

https://github.com/Jakub41/pdf-report-generator/blob/master/lib/pdf/report/generator/cdisc_changes_report.rb#L13

Comment: Ok and what are the rest of parameters I have to pass? What should I do for make it work?

Comment: I don't know, I problably know less about this gem than you (I have never seen it before I saw this question), it's quite specific and not widely used. I guess you'll have to dig through the documentation of this gem or its source to find out how you should use it.